# Nice json format for long lists

Tags: json

How can I format JSON with long lists nicely in terminal/vim?

Default JSON formats (`python -m json.tool`/`jq`) split lists with each item on its own line.
When files contains very long lists (>1000 items), the file becomes very long.

I would like to get something similar to what PyCharm produces when you format JSON.
Lists are continuous, but split when they go over length limit.

EDIT: `pprint(compact=True)` produces desired output, but uses single quotes instead of dobuble quotes

Comment: `%!python -c "import sys, json, pprint; print(pprint.pformat(json.loads(''.join(sys.stdin)), width=120, compact=True).replace(\"'\", '\"'))"` seems to produce required output in vim, but is quite ugly.

Comment: https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli seems like the required tool